# Jetpack WearOS Keyboard merge with UI

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os, gboard

[As similar to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1IAP.png), Is it possible to show UI when the keyboard pops up for samsung(T9) keyboard and Gboard keyboard? Is there any suggestion of how that could be done?

Comment: I think you should implement the custom keyboard in your case. Divide some area in the screen for the text field to display, the rest for keyboard drawing.

Comment: thanks @MurodjonAbdukholikov for the response and valuable suggestion .